# Implement scroll function like on Facebook with React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have an understanding question. If I open Facebook with the desktop and scroll down the main page then switch to my profile which will change the URL to facebook.com/[profile name] and then navigate back again by clicking on the FB logo, then I'm still at the same scroll point as before. No reloading or similar of the page. How do you do that with React? Do I use the react-router-dom useHistory hook?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The behavior you're describing is a result of Facebook's use of a Single Page Application (SPA) architecture. SPAs don't require reloading the entire page when navigating to a different URL within the application. Instead, they only update the necessary parts of the page. This behavior allows the application to maintain your scroll position when navigating back to a previous view.

In a React application, you can achieve similar behavior using the react-router-dom library. Here's how it can work:

React Router: react-router-dom is a standard library for routing in React. It helps in navigating between different components, changing the browser URL, modifying the browser history, and keeping the UI state in sync.

Scroll Restoration: By default, react-router-dom doesn't restore scroll positions when you navigate back to a previous page. However, you can handle this manually. When navigating away from a page, you can save the current scroll position in your application's state. Then, when returning to that page, you can use that saved state to reset the scroll position.

Here's a simple example of how you can implement this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);

  return null;
}

export default ScrollToTop;
```

In the above example, we're using the useLocation hook from react-router-dom to get the current pathname. Then, we use the useEffect hook to call window.scrollTo(0, 0) whenever the pathname changes. This will scroll the user to the top of the page whenever they navigate to a different route.

To use ScrollToTop, you just need to render it somewhere in your app, like inside your main Router component.

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import ScrollToTop from './ScrollToTop';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop />
      {/* your routes here */}
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This will ensure that the scroll position is reset to the top whenever the route changes. However, if you want to maintain the scroll position for specific pages when navigating back, you'll need a more complex solution, such as storing scroll positions in your application's state and restoring them when navigating back to a specific page.

In your case, useHistory wouldn't help to maintain the scroll position. This hook gives you access to the history instance that you may use to navigate. For scroll positions, you'll need to handle it separately as I explained above.